# when installing ireport plugin it shows message as "Some plugins require plugin org.jdesktop.layout to be installed"

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport

I am developing a java project that generate a sales report. I am willing to create the report with jasper report and when I installing the plugins it shows an error as "Some plugins require plugin org.jdesktop.layout to be installed"
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install org.jdesktop.layout plugin too, download link http://137.254.56.27/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/org/netbeans/api/org-jdesktop-layout/RELEASE65/

Comment: The link is broken or I can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install org.jdesktop.layout plugin from the below link

http://137.254.56.27/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/org/netbeans/api/org-jdesktop-layout/RELEASE65/

If you find the above link broken, you can download org.jdesktop.layout plugin or jar or pom from the below link

http://netbeans.apidesign.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/org/netbeans/api/org-jdesktop-layout/RELEASE65/

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

Visit the link and download (org-jdesktop-layout-RELEASE65.nbm) by clicking one time on it

http://netbeans.apidesign.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/org/netbeans/api/org-jdesktop-layout/RELEASE65/

Then Go to Tools | Plugins...
Select the Downloaded tab...
Press Add Plugins…
Select the plugin file.(org-jdesktop-layout-RELEASE65.nbm)...
Install it and finally problem solved....

It worked with me :=)

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to resolve dependency issues is to use dependency management software like Maven. This allows for nested dependencies (like this one) to automatically be brought into the project.